# Having trouble Solving fourth order heat equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, higher-order-logic, linear-pde

I am facing trouble solving this higher order heat equation
$$\partial_t u +\partial_x^4 u = 0,   \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space -\infty<x<\infty, t>0$$ 
$$u(x, t) =0, \space  u_x(x, t) =0, \space  u_{xx}(x, t) =0,\space u_{xxx}(x, t) =0,  \space  as  \space x→±∞, t>0,$$

$$ u(x, 0) = \Theta $$
where $\Theta$ is a Heaviside function. The problem I am facing is I am getting an integration of this hypergeometric function ([hypergeometric function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ4di.png)) 
which I am not able to perform. If anyone can help me solve this problem I would be thankful.

I am sorry that I am not able to post image as my reputation is below 10!

Thank you!

Comment: What are your boundary conditions? Write it out explicitly using [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the suggestion. I have edited the question as per your suggestion. Please check.

Comment: Honestly, I might suggest trying a Laplace transform here if you have to deal with that initial condition. However, you're more than likely to run into a dirac delta of some sort in your solution that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think your boundary conditions do not match the initial condition.  For the Heaviside function initial condition you should have u(x,t) -> 1 as x-> infty while the other conditions are correct.  Actually more than you need really.  The solution to the Cauchy problem should be the Heaviside function convolved with the heat kernel associated with the higher order PDE.  There is no closed form expression but you can compute it numerically.

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).